# VBA get element by id

Tags: vba, excel

Hello  I would appreciate some advice , I need to copy and past some data from webpage to excel  but  I am if this can be possible and how .

Lets' say I have   a file  as :

```
 A        B          
Link     Data
```

I need to open the link on "A"  copy the `<span id="JS_topStoreCount"></span>` result  of the page and Paste on "B"

I have  many rows so has to repeat the same to all the rows

Comment: See if you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334764/need-help-scraping-with-excel-vba/20335096#20335096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function with an XMLHTTP request:

```
Public Function giveMeValue(ByVal link As String) As String
    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
       .Open "POST", link, False
       .send
       htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With
    With htm.getelementbyid("JS_topStoreCount")
       giveMeValue = .innerText
    End With
    htm.Close
    Set htm = Nothing
End Function
```

and just insert the function in the cell, for example in B1:

```
=giveMeValue(A1)
```

Of course, if you prefer not to have a function, you can embed the content of the function into a `Do Loop` and dynamically run only once through all the cells by redefining each time the value of `link` and the place where the `.innerText` should be printed.

Comment: Hi Matteo thank you but I am not sure I can be able to make it

Comment: I mean I tried but doesn't seem to be working , I copied and paste you code in new VBA module  and insert the function in B1
Could you please guide me through

Comment: Well, is there any link in A1 ? If yes, are you sure the link contains that object with that id? Be more specific with the error please, maybe set a breakpoint at the beginning of the code and try to run through step by step.

Comment: Yes In A1 there is link , I may be wrong in the beginning ,  '<span id="JS_topStoreCount"></span>' is inside the html page  and is not included in the link  , so just to understand what I need to copy  , please refer to this page [link](http://tinyurl.com/mzh4aey) on the right of the page  you should see （20） that is what I need to copy

Comment: Just tested with your link and I exactly get 20. What is the error you get on the Excel sheet?

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to  make it work ,  so this is what I did : new excel sheet  , Link in "A1"  and paste '=giveMeValue(A1)' in "B1" . After that  TAB Developer > Visual Basic  > insert Module an paste your code .....after that  doesn't show any result ...miss something ?

Comment: Just to make sure, I tell you what I did: 
1) I create a module;
2) I copy-paste the code (including Function and End Function) into the module (not inside a sub!)
3) I type in any cell "=giveMeValue("
4) I select the cell where the link of the page is
5) I close the bracket and press Enter.
Nothing more, it sounds very strange that it doesn't work. Please give me more info about the error and the behavior, as well as about the Excel version.

Comment: @user2482756 you need to add the function before; just try to press "Enter" on the cell B1, it will work.

Comment: ohhhh is working thx so much  the problem was the Hyperlink , is it possible to  have with the Hyperlink , and what do you mean by "Do Loop and dynamically run only once through all the cells by redefining each time the value of link and the place where the .innerText should be printed." so in real time if numbers change change also the file ?

Comment: If you have the hyperlink, you can write `=giveMeValue(Text(A1,))` instead of simply `=giveMeValue(A1)` (you take only the text part of the hyperlink). For the other question, it's better you close this question (by accepting the answer, if it works) and open a new one because it's very hard to make it by comments.

Comment: Ok  I get it  , thx   sorry but '=giveMeValue(Text(A1,))' is not working from my side with hyperlink , maybe need to change somthing on the module?

Comment: No man, [TEXT](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58) is an Excel built-in function, you're probably just being wrong with the syntaxis. You're on the right way, just try a bit yourself fixing the minor problems and, if it works, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: THX , I accepted the answer   , but to be honest I don't know how to fix it '=giveMeValue(Text(A1,))', so this file will be all the time up to date now ?